# AS2 - Maths Transition Help

Tags: javascript, math, transition, effect

im making a drop down menu in flash and i want it to slide down. At the moment im using a linear slide ( _y += 5, _y -= 5) etc.

I know there are other types of transitions like exponential and the like, how would i go about implementing them? I also remember there was a website once that showed all sorts of slide animations in javascript using different techniques.

Comment: You're using Flash (ActionScript) or JavaScript? Can you show your code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

A simple slide animation would be:

`y = y*(1-speed) + (target_y)*(speed)`

Iterating that causes the box to slide, slowing down as it moves there.  Speed should be between 0 and 1.  With speed 0.5, the distance between the current and target would be halved every moment.

or:

```
t = 0.1
while y < target_y do
y = y + t
t = t + 0.1
end
y = target_y
```

Which causes it to accelerate until it goes beyond the target, where it stops. 
As an alternative to `+ 0.1`, you could do `* 1.1` or something similar, causing an exponential, rather than quadratic, motion.